# Can humanity survive on red planet

Tags: solar-system, planets, exploration

Research is done each and everyday, challenging the boundaries of what we used to think was impossible. After all, it used to be thought impossible to land man on the moon.

Is it possible, give today's technology, to travel to the Mars and start a colony? And if not, what advances would we need to make it possible?

**According to my understanding and personal knowledge discovery.**
**this is how humanity can survive on red planet.**
[image: In brief]

Mars has usable resources such as water ice that could help sustain future expeditionary crews on short missions, or pioneers living permanently on the Red Planet.

But accessing and exploiting Martian water ice and other resources,a process known as In-Situ Resource Utilization (ISRU) is easier said than done. So I think experts have to strategize what’s needed to allow astronauts to maintain a Martian lifestyle on the Red Planet.

Comment: What technology and resources are they allowed to bring to Mars? (And why couldn't they bring the same to the Moon?)

Comment: The simple answer is yes, humans can live on Mars. I don't think anyone is disputing that fact, so it's going to be hard to find anything on it. If you want to know what it'd take or what methods are best/cheapest/fastest, that might be more answerable.

Comment: Welcome to the site Lawrence.  This question isn't fully fleshed out.  Given the right supplies and support structure, yes, humans can survive on Mars.  If you would like an answer though you need to define your scenario better.  Additionally, what does landing on the moon have to do with surviving on Mars?  Take a few minutes to review the [help] when you have time, it outlines well how to write good questions and answers.  Getting the hang of how the SE Q/A model works takes a little time let us know if you have questions in the mean time.

Comment: It takes some getting used to the constraints of this forum, but I hope the edit to your question is more or less what you wanted to ask?

Comment: @Fayth85,I just wanted to make it precise and simple.

Comment: @lawrencecyber 'Precise and simple' is not the same as 'conformed to the guideline of the forum'. James put a link in his comment about the help center to help explain how to do that, so you can keep your question open (or reopen it) so that more people can offer their insights. Otherwise, my advice would be to nose around on the astronomy stack exchange, as they might be more open to this format of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, yes.

Long answer? We have so much research to do, so much innovations that will be needed before such a feat becomes even remotely possible. Why? Where to even begin...

First is the most important: radiation. Because Mars has no magnetosphere, its denizens would not be protected from the background radiation of space (cosmic radiation), nor the blasts from the sun (solar winds). These are things that astronauts (and cosmonauts, and essentially any space traveler) can tell you about, and many have. They tell tales of 'flashes of light as they close their eyes', which is in fact the background radiation striking their retina. This radiation can attack DNA directly, increasing the risk of cancer.

Second up is the lower gravity of the red planet. Yes, it is almost like earth, but it has 0.8G, so 20% less gravity than Earth. This would mean that our muscles and bones would be stronger than the gravity needs it to be, meaning we would lose muscle mass and bone density living there. Though the difference isn't excessive, it is important to keep in mind. Especially when people want to go from Mars to Earth -- their bones and muscles would have exactly the opposite problem.

Then comes the biggest issue: housing. Mars would need a stable habitable area. Check out [Mars 1 Project](http://www.mars-one.com/), seeing as they have the idea already.

So, yes. This is possible, and though it is within our current technological reach, we have so much more to learn and so much growing to do as a society. Time will tell when (not if) this becomes a reality.

Comment: @SteveMangiameli corrections made. And "Where to begin..." is more of a mused murmuring?

Comment: ,Thanks for your answer and effort.Am young supporter of mars-one Project.I just needed more insightful knowledge at mars colonization.